# Prove that $\lim_{x\to b^-}F(x) =L$ if and only if $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists m \in (a,b) \ s.t \forall d,c \in (m,b) \ |F(d)-F(c)|<\varepsilon $

Tags: calculus

Consider $F:[a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ where $a<b\le\infty$. Prove that

$$\lim_{x\to b^-}F(x) \ \ \ \text{exists and is finite} \iff \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists m \in (a,b) \ \text{such that}$$
$$\forall d,c \in (m,b) \ |F(d)-F(c)|<\varepsilon $$

$\Rightarrow$

Let's assume that  $\lim_{x\to b^-}F(x)=L,$ i.e, $$\forall\varepsilon>0, \  \exists \delta>0 : \forall x \in I (0<b-x<\delta \implies|F(x)-L|<\varepsilon)$$ Where $I$ is any interval on the domain of $F$

From that definition, how can I continue? And how can I start $\Leftarrow$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{x\to b^-}F(x)=L$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ consider $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|F(x)-L|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2} \quad\forall x \in [a,b)$ such that $0<b-x<\delta.$ Take $m=b-\delta\in[a,b)$ (with $\delta$ small enough so it makes sense). Then $\forall x,y\in(m,b)$ we have that $0<b-x,b-y<\delta$, so $|F(x)-F(y)|\le|F(x)-L|+|F(y)-L|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$.

Now suppose for any $\varepsilon>0\;$ $\exists m\in(a,b)$ such that $|F(x)-F(y)|<\varepsilon\quad\forall x,y \in (m,b)$. Consider $\varepsilon_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ with its respective $m_n\in[a,b)$. For each $n$ take some element from $(m_n,b)$ and name it $x_n$ (if you don't want to use the axiom of choice, you can choose explicitly, like $x_n=\frac{m_n+b}{2}$ for example). We have a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, but we actually want to consider the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}=\big(F(x_n)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

By construction, we have that $|y_n-y_m|<\varepsilon_{\min({n,m})}=\frac{1}{\min({n,n})}$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\dfrac{1}{n_0}\le\varepsilon$, so for every $m,n\ge n_0$ we have $|y_n-y_m|<\varepsilon_{\min({n,m})}=\frac{1}{\min({n,m})}\le\frac{1}{n_0}\le\varepsilon$, so $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $\Bbb R$ is complete, a Cauchy sequence is convergent, so there must be some $L$ such that $F(x_n)=y_n\rightarrow L$ as $n\to\infty$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, consider $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then there is a $m\in[a,b)$ such that $|F(x)-F(y)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\quad\forall x,y \in (m,b)$. There must be some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\dfrac{1}{n_0}\le\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Besides, there must be some $n_1$ such that $|F(x_n)-L|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for every $n\ge n_1$, so instead of considering $m$ let's consider $M=\max({m_{n_0},m_{n_1}})\in[a,b)$. Let's say $M=m_{n_i}$. Take $\delta=b-M>0$, then $\forall x\in[a,b)$ such that $0<x<\delta$ we have $x\in(M,b)$, so $|F(x)-L|\le|F(x)-F(x_{n_i})|+|F(x_{n_i})-L|<\dfrac{1}{n_0}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\le\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$, so $\lim_{x\to b^-}F(x)=L$.

Answer (score 0):

For the $\implies$ direction pick $m\in(a, b)$ such that for every $x$ and $y$ in $(m, b)$ we have $|F(x)-F(y)|<\varepsilon/2$ and then use the triangle inequality. For the $\impliedby$ direction let $(x_n)_{n  =0}^{\infty}$ be any sequence in $(a, b)$ converging to $b$. Then show that the sequence $(F(x_{n}))_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy and hence convergent. Finally show that for any two sequences $(x_{n})_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ and $(y_{n})_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ in $(a, b)$ converging to $b$ the sequences $(F(x_{n}))_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ and $(F(y_{n}))_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ must have the same limit (use contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the $\Leftarrow$ direction: use the hypothesis to show that $\limsup_{x \to b^-} F(x) = \liminf_{x\to b^-} F(x)$ is finite, and then show that if the common value is $L$, then $\lim_{x\to b^-} F(x) = L$ also.  Here,
$\limsup_{x\to b^-} F(x) = \inf_{c \in (a, b)} \sup_{x \in (c, b)} F(x)$ and similarly $\liminf_{x\to b^-} F(x) = \sup_{c\in (a, b)} \inf_{x \in (c, b)} F(x)$.

In this proof, you can reuse a lot of the ideas from the proof you've probably already seen that a Cauchy sequence is convergent.